# Replace a string in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to replace a string in SQL.
E.g: from `,1,,2,3,` to `1|2|3`

I'm using `REPLACE()` function but I can't find regex to replace it:

```
SELECT REPLACE(',1,,2,3,',',','|') 
  FROM dual;
```

Hope everyone help me.

Comment: Either do several REPLACE, or perhaps a REGEX_REPLACE. Anyway, storing data as comma/vertical bar separated values will cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Hi Duy, welcome to SO, please read [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still will need to `REGEXP_REPLACE`: one for inner commas and one for boundaries of your string.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(',1,,2,3,', ',+', '|', 'g'),'^\||\|$','','g');
```

EDIT: to use with Oracle

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(',1,,2,3,', ',+', '|'),'^\||\|$','') from dual;
```

Comment: Assuming OP is using Oracle (DUAL...), the 'ORA-01722: invalid number' error is raised.

Comment: @jarlh, completely missed dual in question, thank you. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL use REGEXP_REPLACE :

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '|' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '[[,]]+', '|')) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to replace all non-digits with a pipe only once per each portion of non-digit occurence, and then trim the pipes stay at the beginning and the end by using

```
SELECT TRIM( BOTH '|' FROM REGEXP_REPLACE(',1,,2,3,','[^[:digit:]]+','|') ) 
  FROM dual
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xUSKWPsd)</kbd>